# Entity Framework insert using Z.EntityFramework's SingleInsertAsync method returning IDENTITY

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-plus

I want to insert a single record into my database using the Z Entity Framework Extensions and the `SingleInsertAsync` method. However, I need the ID of the freshly inserted entity. How can I get that? I can literally find no documentation for this method.

Here's my code:

```cs
Specification newSpecification = db.Specifications.Create();

newSpecification.ID_Feature = featureID;
newSpecification.Specification1 = specificationKey;

await db.Specifications.SingleInsertAsync(newSpecification);

int id = newSpecification.ID;
```

The variable `id` is obviously 0 after the insert. How can I get the actual ID there? Unfortunately, `SingleInsertAsync` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

The `SingleInsert` works exactly like the `BulkInsert` method, so you can use the same documentation.

The method doesn't return the identity but should populate automatically the identity value.

If the `Specification` have the `ID` specified as identity, the value will be automatically populated.

See the following online example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/h9Psm7

Comment: Doesn't work in my project. After calling `SingleInsertAsync`, the ID property of my Entity (which is set to be an IDENTITY value) is still 0.

Comment: Hello @AndréReichelt, please contact our support with a project. That's pretty much impossible at this moment to know exactly why it doesn't work for you.